# Populate fieldset without Doctrine-ORM annotation

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

hy,

is it possible to populate a fieldset, without having the corresponding attribute mapped with doctrine-orm annotation?

My problem is that I have an entity called Offer, I have an OfferForm and with this form I want to be able to edit another Entity called Address. The Address is a fieldset called AddressFieldset and is added to the OfferForm like this:

```
class OfferForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($em)
    {
        parent::__construct('offer');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em))
             ->setObject(new Offer());

        $this->add(new AddressFieldset($em));
    }
}
```

The AddressFieldset looks something like this:

```
class AddressFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    public function __construct($em)
    {
        parent::__construct('address');
        // ... form-fields
    }
}
```

If I map the Address in the Offer entity with ORM mapping everything works fine, the fiedset gets populated with the data from the address. Here is the address attribute in the Offer entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Contact\Entity\Address")
 */
private $address;
```

If I remove the annotation, the address fieldset doesn't get populated with the address data:

```
private $address;
```

even if I set the address in the controller:

```
$offer->setAddress($address);
```

The problem is, I don't want to have a relation from offer to address in the database (with the one-to-one relation), but otherwise it doesn't seem to work :-(

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I your question totally, but I will try to answer.

If you don't want an address column in your offer table in the database but you still want to associate them then you should define a [`one-to-one`, `BiDirectional`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) relation from address to offer so address becomes the owning side and offer the inverse side.
Resulting in a offer column in your address table in the database. This sounds illogical to me, I would say the offer should be the owning side, but it is possible like this...

So in your address:

```
/** ONE-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, OWNING SIDE
 * @var Offer
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Offer", inversedBy="address")
 */
private $offer;
```

In your offer:

```
/** ONE-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, INVERSE SIDE
 * @var Address
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Address", mappedBy="offer")
 */
private $address;
```

Comment: well that would work too, but as you already noticed it will result in an offer column in the address table, which I don't want to. What I have figured out is, that the entities need some sort of relation in the database, in other words, they need to be connected within the db-model. It seems that what I wan't is simply not possible. But thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I don't see how you want to you relate something without adding column in the database? If there is no relation between offer and address in the database how do you know which address belongs to which offer?

Comment: the address doesn't really belongs to the offer, I just want to be able to edit an address (doesn't matter which address) within the offer form. Thats why I didn't wanted to have that address<->offer relation.